# Validate Status of a Request Rest Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the following code

```
this.http.post("http://api/user", JSON.stringify(this.params), options)
        .subscribe(
        res => this.obj = res,//info = res,
        err => console.error(err),);
```

If this request returns me a 200 I want to move to another window and I have this

```
if (this.obj.status == 200){this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);}
```

but `this.obj.status` is undefined

How can I have the status value outside of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show, where in your code `this.obj.status == 200` is executed, but probably it is before your http request has resolved.
If you send an HTTP request, it returns an Observable, which is asynchronous. That means, that the `.subscribe()` call will terminate before the response comes back; it is non-blocking. Everything after the `.subscribe()` will be executed immediately.

Hence, you should do your conditional redirect **within** your `.subscribe()`. The block within will be executed only when the request is resolved (with a result or an error).

```
.subscribe(
  res => {
     if (res.status === 200) {
       this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
     }
  }
  err => ...
)
```

Read more about that at https://angular.io/guide/http

As stated in the comments by JGFMK: This will solve your problem in the most basic way, but does not conform to good architectural style. If you want to improve the solution further, the service responsible for the http requests should just return the Observable (without the subscribe). The component that uses this service can then subscribe to the responses and react on them, i.e. perform a redirect.

Comment: This works. But the subscribe should be in the component.. and the post in a service. i.e. You shouldn't be injecting navCtrl into the service..

Comment: @JGFMK: Thanks for your comment. I've added your remarks to my answer.

Comment: Yes, That's what was happening to me.
Thanks, is that I'm just getting started on ionic

Comment: @Vega why do you think so? 200 is the http status code for OK, I don't think angular will reject a response with a 200. In my understanding, all responses starting with a 2 or 3 will be resolved.